# Cannot output laravel model getter property containing array

Tags: laravel, mutators

I want to have model property containing array of files from specific directory

```
public function getGalleryAttribute($value) {
  return Storage::disk('storage')->files($value);
}
```

then I output on the page

```
@foreach ($item->gallery as $img)
  <img src="/storage/{{ $img }}" >
@endforeach
```

and I see error

```
Attempt to read property "gallery" on array (View: /var/www/site/resources/views/components/postpartials/gallery.blade.php)
```

I cannot understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($item->gallery->isNotEmpty()) {
   
}
```

try checking if the gallery property exists in the array and if there is some sort of data stored in that
just use dd($item);

Comment: it seems that it was mistype. Issue is closed. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it was mistype. Issue is closed.